# Will a work done be infinite if a body in empty space keeps moving after a force is applied and displacement keeps increasing

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

Assume the mass of the body to be 1kg.
Initial velocity 5mps. Final velocity 15mps. Force applied 10N in direction of motion.
There is nothing around the object it is in empty space.
Without using work done = 1/2 mv²
Taking Work as Force × Displacement what will be the work done? Infinite?
But it can't be, right?
What will be the Displacement?
I think we need to put time into the equation.
I am sorry if it's a silly question to post here.

Comment: Why do you think it will be infinite in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Force of 10N applied says acceleration is a=F/m=10m/s^2 to go from 5mps=8000m/s to 15mps=166000m/s you can calculate the time t with $166000m/s =a*t+8000m/s$ with known time you calculate the way $s=a/2t^2+8000m/s*t$ and finally the work done $W=F*s$ continuing moving does not ad to the energy of the body wich will be $E=1/2kg*(166000m/s)^2$